# Jmeter shows an error occurred while copying node when copying an element

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I keep getting an error message whenever I cut/copy an element in Jmeter.
System params are like:

1. macOS Sierra 10.13.6
2. java version "1.8.0_191"
3. Jmeter 5.1

The error log looks something like this.
One more note as well, I had to instances running in GUI mode at the same time.
**This behavior also happens mostly whenever I try to Cut ( Command + X) and element.**

[image]

```
2019-03-08 10:12:30,829 INFO o.j.r.PluginManager: Plugins Status: [jpgc-graphs-basic=2.0, jpgc-sense=3.5, jpgc-cmd=2.2, jpgc-csl=0.1, jpgc-functions=2.1, jpgc-casutg=2.8, jpgc-graphs-dist=2.0, jpgc-ggl=2.0, jpgc-jmxmon=0.2, jpgc-mergeresults=2.1, jpgc-perfmon=2.1, jpgc-plugins-manager=1.3, bzm-random-csv=0.6, jpgc-webdriver=3.0, jpgc-xml=0.1, jmeter-core=5.1, jmeter-ftp=5.1, jmeter-http=5.1, jmeter-jdbc=5.1, jmeter-jms=5.1, jmeter-junit=5.1, jmeter-java=5.1, jmeter-ldap=5.1, jmeter-mail=5.1, jmeter-mongodb=5.1, jmeter-native=5.1, jmeter-tcp=5.1, jmeter-components=5.1]
2019-03-08 10:12:32,613 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-03-08 10:12:32,615 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-03-08 10:12:32,615 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-03-08 10:12:32,615 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2019-03-08 10:12:32,615 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2019-03-08 10:12:32,615 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2019-03-08 10:12:32,915 INFO o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool'
2019-03-08 10:12:32,916 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file /Users/XXXX/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/proxyserver.jks
2019-03-08 10:12:33,094 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='/Users/XXXX/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin'
2019-03-08 10:12:33,530 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2019-03-08 10:12:33,530 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2019-03-08 10:12:33,531 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2019-03-08 10:12:33,531 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2019-03-08 10:12:38,571 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Load: Loading file: /Users/XXXX/bitbucket/vuares/src/test/jmeter/more_jmeter3.jmx
2019-03-08 10:12:38,571 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/Users/XXXX/bitbucket/vuares/src/test/jmeter'
2019-03-08 10:12:38,710 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2019-03-08 10:12:38,713 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2019-03-08 10:12:38,715 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2019-03-08 10:12:38,718 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: /Users/XXXX/bitbucket/vuares/src/test/jmeter/more_jmeter3.jmx
2019-03-08 10:12:39,022 INFO o.a.j.p.h.c.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_
2019-03-08 10:12:39,041 INFO o.a.j.p.h.c.CacheManager: Will only cache the following methods: [GET]
2019-03-08 10:12:40,055 WARN o.a.j.t.g.GenericTestBeanCustomizer: kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener#graphWidth(int) has a DEFAULT of class java.lang.String
2019-03-08 10:12:40,056 WARN o.a.j.t.g.GenericTestBeanCustomizer: kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener#graphHeight(int) has a DEFAULT of class java.lang.String
2019-03-08 10:12:40,269 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/Users/XXXX/bitbucket/vuares/src/test/jmeter'
2019-03-08 10:12:51,665 ERROR o.a.j.g.a.Copy: Clipboard node read error: com.bulenkov.darcula.ui.DarculaComboBoxUI
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.bulenkov.darcula.ui.DarculaComboBoxUI
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.writeObject(JComponent.java:5515) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3690) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3690) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3690) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.writeObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode.java:1287) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.Vector.writeObject(Vector.java:1103) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.writeObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode.java:1278) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode.writeObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode.java:1278) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterTreeNodeTransferable.setTransferData(JMeterTreeNodeTransferable.java:85) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Copy.setCopiedNodes(Copy.java:119) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Cut.doAction(Cut.java:56) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.doActionNow(ActionRouter.java:125) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeListener.keyPressed(JMeterTreeListener.java:219) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:250) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6497) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6316) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:835) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1103) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:974) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:800) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93) [?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) [?:1.8.0_191]
```

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

Change LAF from Darcula to System:

[image: LAF change]

Root cause:

This is a bug, but since I don't reproduce it on Mac OSX with core jmeter 5.1.1 / JDK 8u201. So it probably comes from 3rd party plugins you have in your plan.
Can you try with a core jmeter and see if you reproduce ?
Then submit a bug at:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html

Comment: I changed the to system theme and I see the application is more stable and I couldn't reproduce the issue yet. Thanks for taking the time to check it.